# COUNT for IN statement (count from scope, not from a table)

Tags: python, mysql, sql

My question is pretty simple:

I want to select user_id, count(user_id) from a scope (not from a table). Is this even possible?

Example:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5);
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
id| count
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 2
5 | 1
```

My really code:

```
set_of_user_ids = (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id IN %s', (set_of_user_ids,))
```

Comment: Good and versatille solution is to crate a table-valued user function that returns table from string of separated values and then perform SELECT over it.

Answer (score 1):

With Recursive CTE you can achieve this.

```
with recursive
    idlist as ( select '1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5' as userids),
    idlist1 as ( select 1 as n 
                 union 
                 select n + 1 from idlist1, idlist
                 where n <= length(userids) - length(replace(userids, ',', '')))
    select USERS.id,count(1)
    from (
    select substring_index(substring_index(userids, ',', n), ',', -1)id 
    from idlist,idlist1) idlist
    inner join USERS ON idlist.id = USERS.id
   group by id
```

Output is :

```
id  count(1)
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   2
5   1
```

Refer demo on dbfiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3da3fab675cfee86f897797f201085ae

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is too confusing. I think I chose the wrong approach. I just have to use a `temporary table` instead of the `WHERE IN` construct.
I did not know that my question does not have a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table and `left join`:

```
select user_id, count(u.user_id)
from (select 1 as user_id union all
      select 2 as user_id union all
      select 2 as user_id union all
      . . .
     ) t left join
     users u
     using (user_id)
group by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not suitable for a large data set

Comment: @ДавидШико . . . Why not?  It is definitely suitable for the data in the question you asked.  And it is easily generalizable to many more ids.